# FormTypeMapping not working with SonataCoreBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, symfony-3.3

I am trying to use some bundles from sonata project for editing a 1:N association:

A `MediaList` can have many `Media` objects assigned. The doctrine configuration is correct, so is the configuration of `MediaAdmin` which is the admin class for my `Media` entity. The MediaList admin should embed the form for my Media and allow adding / removing items to the list:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('media', 'sonata_type_collection',
            [
                'by_reference' => false,
            ],
            [
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ]);
    }
```

In symfony 3, the support for string formtypes such as "sonata_type_collection" has been dropped. However, the SonataCoreBundle adds some functionality that should re-enable this feature (see [documentation 3.1](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html)).

Unfortunately this is not working for me and I get an InvalidArgumentException (Could not load type "sonata_type_collection")

- I made sure `FormHelper::registerFormTypeMapping` in `SonataCoreBundle` and `SonataAdminBundle` gets called with a breakpoint and debugging.
- I tried using the FQCN instead (`Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType`) but sonata then uses `sonata_type_admin` internally which fails when I press the "add" button
- It worked a few days ago and fails since I ran `composer update` without changing anything in my composer.json

So how do I use these form types in Symfony 3.X? Is there any additional config needed?

My composer.json (not all entries, but I think the most relevant):

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.20.1",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
"symfony/symfony": "3.3.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a configuration that is working for me.
I had `minimum-stability` in my composer.json set to `dev`. After changing it to `stable` and update it works again.